# Detect all beans have been instantiated in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to ask is there anyway to detect all beans have been instantiated in Spring framework ?

I'm using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext class of Spring library to load in my Spring configuration XML.

I do understand that I can get all beans after they are been instantiated in bean factory. My dumb solution is by using getBean(String name) method in Spring API and check against with all desired beans in the Spring configuration XML. If all desired beans can be found, I can infer that all beans have been instantiated.

The reason I don't prefer the dumb solution is anytime I update my configuration XML, I need to update my source code of checking against again. If this solution has more vulnerabilities, please feel free to point out.

Thanks your time and kindly suggestions

Comment: when you start your application in the console you can see your spring beans. You can check that by searching for a known bean

Comment: @Fede Is that my dumb solution perform?

Comment: I don't understand why you are checking if the bean is instantiated. Do you not trust spring? Or trust the xml you write?

Comment: @ohiocowboy Good query, I'm trust Spring and already tested the XML I wrote. Worked fine. But I need to let my system deleted those configuration XML files after all beans have been successfully loaded and instantiate. This a consideration from security concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a BeanPostProcessor to your context

```
class B1 implements BeanPostProcessor {
    List beans = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        beans.add(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    List getBeans() {
        return beans;
    }
...
```

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev, after I got the all beans instantiated from BeanPostProcessory, I think I still need to check against the desired beans in my configuration file, isn't it ?

Comment: I think you dont need it, postProcessBeforeInitialization will be called for all beans in configuration, so the list will contain all available beans

Answer (score 0):

What about using [getBeansOfType(Object.class)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html%23getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-)?

You will get a map containing all name-bean pairs in the application context. The is also a version to include non singletons, but you will get top level beans only.